# Regular expression to find last item name

Tags: php, regex

So I have a string as follows

```
Continent | Country | Region | State | Area | Town
```

Sometimes the string is

```
Continent | Country | Region | State | Area
```

What would be the regular expression to grab the last entry (i.e. either Town or Area)?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex!

```
$str = 'Continent|Country|Region|State|Area';

$exp = explode('|', $str);

echo end($exp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone does want the regex (also removes preceding spaces):

```php
$string = 'Continent | Country | Region | State | Area | Town';

preg_match('/[^|\s]+$/', $string, $last);
echo $last;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regular expression with this when you can achieve the same with [PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php):

```
$segments = explode(' | ', 'Continent | Country | Region | State | Area | Town');
echo end($segments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

```
$str = 'Continent|Country|Region|State|Area';
$last = substr(strrchr($str,'|'),1);
```

Please note this only works if there is more than one item or strrchr will return false.